# Criar atributos "dependentes" no Magento

Tags: javascript, html, magento, cms

Estou tentando fazer atributos que dependam do outro no Magento, por exemplo, tem dois generos (Masculino | Femininho), se o usuário escolher Masculino, no atributo tamanho, ficarão disponiveis as opções P, M, G e GG e se ele escolher Feminino, as opções G e GG ficarão indisponíveis ou não irão aparecer, ja fucei pra caramba e não consegui achar isso rs... Alguém tem ideia de como fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não existe isso de atributos dependentes, o que acontece é uma combinação dos produtos disponíveis por exemplo:

Você vai criar no Magento o atributo tamanho, e vai definir ele com as opções:
P , m , G, GG
E também vai criar o atributo Cor:
Azul, Amarelo, Vermelho

Quando você for criar o produto, vai criar ele como Produto Simples e definir o tamanho e a cor
por exemplo você tem 4 produtos:
P - Azul
M - Amarelo
M - Vermelho

Depois você vai criar um produto configuravel que vai ser o agrupamento desses produtos simples e ele vai criar as opções automaticamente de acordo com os produtos simples associados.

Logo quando o cliente no frontend marcar P , ele vai disponibilizar somente a opção de cor Azul e se ele marcar M vai aparecer Amarelo e vermlho, por exemplo.

Comment: Vlw mano, consegui resolver do jeito q vc me passou msm kkk